# Git conflict with pull --rebase on unrelated file

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I have a repo where I'm seeing behavior that I don't understand.

Ill refer to the repo that this is occuring on as the 'bad repo', all of the following sequences were run on that one.

It doesn't matter what commit I reset to, same conflicting behavior. The files it reports as conflicting seem to be the ones that were changed in the commit I reset to.

1) Sequence 2 is only happening on the 'bad repo', the same sequence of commands results in no conflicts on a fresh clone, or any one else's. What is it about the one persons repo could be causing this?

2) Why would adding an arbitrary file in sequence 2 cause the pull --rebase to conflict? It worked fine as in sequence 1 when there was no changes.

3) Basically, I don't understand why sequence 2 is causing conflicts, given that 1,3,4 all work fine.

```
.git/config has:

[branch "media"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/media
```

Here are the sequences of commands I'm running and the results:

### Sequence 1(reset and pull)

```
$ git reset --hard 68a170d
HEAD is now at 68a170d Fixes issues with nested attribute sites

$ git status
# On branch media
# Your branch is behind 'origin/media' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded media to 4c7d9cf046368d4c7770d3b590bf3c1d1f14d480.
```

### Sequence 2(reset add file pull)

```
$ git reset --hard 68a170d
HEAD is now at 68a170d Fixes issues with nested attribute sites

$ touch someblahrandomfile
$ git add someblahrandomfile
$ git commit -m 'blah'
[media 9bf2bfb] blah
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 someblahrandomfile

$ git status
# On branch media
# Your branch and 'origin/media' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 7 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Fixed verify methods
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app/controllers/jet_controller.rb
Auto-merging app/models/claim.rb
Auto-merging app/models/site.rb
Auto-merging app/models/user.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/models/user.rb
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Fixed verify methods

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

### Sequence 3(reset add file pull with extra params)

```
$ git reset --hard 68a170d
HEAD is now at 68a170d Fixes issues with nested attribute sites

$ touch zz
$ git add zz
$ git commit -m 'blah4'
[media c79214d] blah4
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 zz

$ git status
# On branch media
# Your branch and 'origin/media' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 7 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git pull --rebase -- origin media
 * branch            media      -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: blah4
```

### Sequence 4(reset and rebase)

```
$ git reset --hard 68a170d
HEAD is now at 68a170d Fixes issues with nested attribute sites

$ touch vv
$ git add vv
$ git commit -m 'blah7'
[media 6c3f42b] blah7
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 vv

$ git status
# On branch media
# Your branch and 'origin/media' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 7 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git rebase origin/media
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: blah7
```

### Additional Info

a) The bad repo is on a Mac osx 10.6.4
b) Git 1.7.1
c)

```
color.branch=auto
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch.current=yellow reverse
color.branch.local=yellow
color.branch.remote=green
color.diff.meta=yellow bold
color.diff.frag=magenta bold
color.diff.old=red bold
color.diff.new=green bold
color.status.added=yellow
color.status.changed=green
color.status.untracked=cyan
merge.tool=opendiff
mergetool.tool=opendiff
difftool.difftool=opendiff
gui.recentrepo=/git/MYREPO
user.name=USER
user.email=EMAIL
alias.wtf=git-wtf
alias.lg=log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=URL
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.media.remote=origin
branch.media.merge=refs/heads/media
```

### Update 2 (first set of >>> should be pointing the other way but couldn't get them displaying correctly)

```
$ git diff
diff --cc app/models/user.rb
index e1c31e2,f4923e6..0000000
--- a/app/models/user.rb
+++ b/app/models/user.rb

    has_many :coupon_codes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :coupon_codes

 >>>>>>> HEAD
 =======
    has_many :sites, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sites, :allow_destroy => true

 >>>>>>> Fixed verify methods
```

Comment: Sequence 2 is the only one that's applying the change introduced by the "Fixed verify methods" commit.  Sequence 1 is just fast-forwarding, whereas the other ones are cherry-picking commits that only introuduce new files.  This guess may be totally off, but I wonder if this is an issue with the autocrlf setting in bad_repo, so that line-endings are causing the patch to fail - perhaps you could add (a) the platform that bad_repo is on (b) the version of git you're using in these examples and (c) output from "git config --list" (particularly for the core.autocrlf setting)

Comment: I updated the post with the info you requested

tl;dr: osx 10.6.4, git 1.7.1, no autocrlf setting.

Comment: Thanks - not that then :(  What does `git diff` tell you about the conflict?

Comment: Added the results of running git diff during the rebase, I don't see much useful info there..

Comment: One extra piece of info, performing a git --rebase -p does not result in conflicts.

Comment: @thebaldwin: If the conflict doesn't appear, then you're presumably rebasing a branch containing a merge commit; with the merge commit preserved, everything's fine, but if you remove it, a later change no longer applies.

Comment: @jefromi That seems reasonable, does that apply at all to the difference in results from git pull --rebase and git pull --rebase -- origin media?

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten (not for the first time) that "can be fast-forwarded" doesn't imply linear history.  Sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Why are you rebasing?  I see no need in your scenarios above to use it.  Rebase **rewrites history**.

Scenario 1:

> Your branch is behind 'origin/media' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.

So fast forward it!  `git merge origin/media` or simply `git pull`, `--rebase` is overkill, *you have nothing to be applied*.

You are here:
`A1`

origin/media is here:
`A1-A2-A3-A4-A5-A6-A7-A8` (and so on) it's linear just fast-forward with a merge.

Fast-forwarding *moves a pointer*.  Rebasing stashes changes (which you have none, if it says you can ff) and then reapplies your commits **as new commits**, re-writing history.  But you have none, so this is just wasteful jumping through hoops.

Scenario 2:

Again, why are you rebasing?  Rebasing **rewrites history** with new commits.  If you do not need to **reorder history** then do not **reorder history**

Scenario 2 gives you problems because `git pull --rebase` will rebase your current branch with the default branch from default remote (`origin master`).  In the config, you have `branch.media.merge` setup, but not `branch.media.rebase`.  Hence, `git pull` (which runs merge by default) will pull from `origin media`, but `git pull --rebase` will pull from `origin master` (the default).  This also explains why Scenario 3 and 4 work: you're explicitly telling it what branch/source to rebase from.

From `man git-config`:

> `branch.<name>.rebase`
>
> ```
>        When true, rebase the branch <name> on top of the fetched branch, instead of merging the default branch from the default remote when
>        "git pull" is run.  NOTE: this is a possibly dangerous operation; do not use it unless you understand the implications (see git-
>        rebase(1) for details).
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, that makes sense for scenario 3 and 4. The piece I'm still not quite understanding is in scenario 2 when I add a non existent file (or presumably files which don't conflict with either master or media changes). Shouldn't git be able to stash my changes, putting it into essentially the same situation as scenario 1, do the FF and then apply my changes?